# Android - How to limit number of specific Worker instances running in parallel in WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I was wondering is there any way to limit number of parallel workers of only one type.

So I have UploadWorker, witch backups single file. I want to be able to limit how much uploads go in parallel.

And with

```
    val configuration = Configuration.Builder()
    .setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))
    .build()
WorkManager.initialize(context, configuration)
```

it is all good for upload part.
I can just dump work requests as I collect new items for upload.

But I have other Workers, and I do not want for UploadWorker work requests to finish, but I want those to run as soon as possible.

How can I manage that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.

If I use regular worker for UploadWorker, and CoroutineWorker for others, then UploadWorker will run on configured Executor, while CoroutineWorker runs on default Dispatcher or any other that I want.